# Flow 'unexpected token <' for jsx code in IDE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

For some reason my ide is printing out 'Unexpected token <. Remember, adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing parent tag' for the following react code. I don't understand why it's printing that error since the component it's referring to is wrapped in an enclosing parent tag the `<TableBody>` tag specifically.

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react'
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody'
import Roster from './roster.jsx'
import type { MembersType } from '../../typeDefs/MembersType.js'


type RanksType = {
  _id: string | number,
  rankName: string,
  members: Array<MembersType>
};

export default (props: {
  members: MembersType
}) => (
  <TableBody>
    {props.members.map(({ 
      _id,
      rankName,
      members,
    }: RanksType) => (
      <Roster <---specifically refering to this element
        key={_id}
        rank={rankName}
        members={members}
      />
    ))}
  </TableBody>
)
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "novacms",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor --settings settings-production.json --port $IP:$PORT",
    "dev": "meteor --settings settings-development.json --port $IP:$PORT",
    "test": "meteor test --driver-package cultofcoders:mocha --port $IP:$PORT"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@novacms/assign": "^1.0.0",
    "@novacms/dependancy-injector": "^1.0.0",
    "@novacms/event-store": "^1.0.0",
    "@novacms/extend": "^1.0.0",
    "@novacms/extendschema": "^1.0.1",
    "@novacms/has": "^1.0.0",
    "@novacms/pipe": "^1.0.0",
    "@novacms/type-check": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "event-emitter": "^0.3.5",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "meteor-apihelper": "^1.0.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.3.3",
    "mobx": "^3.6.1",
    "mobx-react": "^4.4.2",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "npm": "^5.10.0",
    "prettier": "^1.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-storybook": "^1.0.0",
    "recompose": "^0.26.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.79.1",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.4.2",
    "simpl-schema-mockdoc": "^1.0.5",
    "sinon": "^4.5.0",
    "spacejam": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-meteor": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-meteor": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.46.3"

  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

VSCode config

```
{
    "files.eol": "\r\n",
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Mono', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        "./src",
        "./client",
        "./imports",
        "./server"
    ],
    "react.beautify.onSave": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "javascript.format.enable": false,
}
.babelrc

{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties", "syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Comment: What is the IDE? Is that IDE complaining about that or it's not compiling ?

Comment: VS Code, it's complaining about it and not compiling.

Comment: It is configuration issue. Show your configuration files & package.json

Comment: updated with the configuration and package.json

Comment: Oh. You're using mentor to generate React Boilerplate Code ? You need `.jsx` extension . Not `.js` ..... Make sure your file extension is correct

Comment: Just for debugging purpose, if you remove `<Roster />`, is this working?

Comment: Another one think I've noticed, in `package.json`, you need `"eslintConfig": { "parser": "babel-eslint"}`

Comment: The extensions are correct, if I remove the roster element and replace it with a div the same error pops up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171413/discussion-between-user3655510-and-ritwick-dey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar issue. 
Firstly delete (rename) your .babelrc file which you use (remove where ever you set it).

If storybook can't find that file, then it will use its own settings.  This worked for me to prove that it was that file that caused the issue.

If this is the same for you then create a new .babelrc file, and place it into the storybook folder.  Storybook will now use this and your project can continue to use the existing one.

The tricky part is finding the config setting in you existing .babelrc file that is breaking storybook - for me it was the `react-hot-load/babel`, but you don't have that listed.

My file ended up with only `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-rest-spread` for plugins.